# Способ для того, чтобы скрыть выпадающее меню

Tags: меню, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Что необходимо добавить или изменить здесь

```
        append_to.click( function(){
            if ( $(this).hasClass('closed') ){
                $(this).removeClass( 'closed' ).addClass( 'opened' );
                $cloned_nav.slideDown( 500 );
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass( 'opened' ).addClass( 'closed' );
                $cloned_nav.slideUp( 500 );
            }
            return false;
        } );

        append_to.find('a').click( function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        } );
    }
```

чтобы меню скрывалось при клике все самого меню. Спасибо !

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос точнее и добавьте код меню.

Answer (score 2):

Давно на jQuery не писал, но передам вам идею. Суть в том, что ловим все события по документу, проверяем и если `e.target` не принадлежит нашему элементу, то закрываем, иначе - ничего не делаем.

```
function close () {
    // your close code here
    $(document).off('click', fullDocumentCallback);
}

function fullDocumentCallback (e) {
    if ( !append_to.find(e.target).length ) {
        close();
    }
}

$(document).on('click', fullDocumentCallback);
```

Как альтернатива - можно сделать огромный полупрозрачный overlay-элемент на весь экран с абсолютной позицией и над всеми элементами и ловить события на нём. Заодно акцентируете людям на вашем выпадающем меню.